# ¿Se pueden utilizar y enviar datos de una clase cuyo atributo sea un arreglo predefinido?

Tags: java, poo, class

Estoy desarrollando un programa cuyo ambiente es una pizzería. Basado en el enunciado pensé en definir una clase para la pizza que se vaya a armar a medida que avanza el proceso de pedido. Lo que quiero lograr es utilizar un arreglo predefinido dentro de esta clase para facilitar el manejo de algunos datos como el ingrediente y su tamaño.

Actualmente mi idea era esta pero el visual studio code me envia un mensaje que solo se puede predefinir al momento de inicializar la variable, en este caso, el arreglo.

```
public class Pizza {
    String[] ingrediente;
    String[] ingredientes_adicionales = new String[4];
    String[] tamaño;
    double[] precio;

    public Pizza(String[] ingrediente, String[] tamaño, float[] precio) {
        this.ingrediente = {"Jamón", "Pepperoni", "Pollo", "Vegetariana"};
        this.tamaño = {"Personal", "Familiar"};
        this.precio = {5.50, 12.00};
    }

    public String[] getIngrediente() {
        return ingrediente;
    }

    public String[] getTamaño() {
        return tamaño;
    }

    public float[] getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }
}
```

Destaco que debido a que se trata de arreglos, al utilizar el get de alguno de ellos, solo devuelve la posición de memoria.

Dado el hecho que de esta forma no funciona ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo funcionar desde la clase o me veo obligado a utilizar los datos desde la función donde se vayan a utilizar?

Modifique la clase para utilizarlo de esta forma en función de las recomendaciones:

```
public class Pizza {
    String[] tipos = new String[4];
    String[] ingredientes_adicionales = new String[4];
    String[] tamaños = new String[2];
    double[] precios = new double[2];
    double precio_ingrediente_adicional;

    public Pizza() {
        this.tipos[0]="Jamón";
        this.tipos[1]="Pepperoni";
        this.tipos[2]="Pollo";
        this.tipos[3]="Vegetariana";
        
        this.ingredientes_adicionales[0]="Jamón";
        this.ingredientes_adicionales[1]="Pepperoni";
        this.ingredientes_adicionales[2]="Pollo";
        this.ingredientes_adicionales[3]="Hongos";

        this.tamaños[0]="Personal";
        this.tamaños[1]="Familiar";

        this.precios[0]=5.50;
        this.precios[1]=12.00;

        this.precio_ingrediente_adicional=1.00;
    }

    public String getTipos(int n_ingrediente) {
        return this.tipos[n_ingrediente];
    }

    public String getTamaños(int n_tamaño) {
        return this.tamaños[n_tamaño];
    }

    public String getIngredientes_adicionales(int n_ingrediente_adicional){
        return this.ingredientes_adicionales[n_ingrediente_adicional];
    }

    public double getPrecios(int n_precio) {
        return this.precios[n_precio];
    }

    public double getPrecio_ingrediente_adicional (){
        return precio_ingrediente_adicional;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Destaco que debido a que se trata de arreglos, al utilizar el get de alguno de ellos, solo devuelve la posición de memoria.* -> Mentira. Lo que pasará es que estás intentando imprimir así: `System.out.println(ingredientes);`... y como se trata de un objeto (un array en este caso), no sabe cómo imprimírtelo así que te da la referencia. Prueba a imprimirlo con `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ingredientes))` y verás. Por otro lado, el problema es que en tu constructor recibes los 3 parámetros, pero no los usas!! Borra esos parámetros del `public Pizza(...)` y ya está

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración de lo del print. En caso de querer usar el arregloa traves del get para conseguir datos especificos ¿deberé modificarlo para que me traiga el dato por medio de un parámetro? es decir, `x = ingrediente[a]`

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres... ese get devuelve un array. Quieres que devuelva unicamente un ingrediente? Tal como está hecho, lo normal sería que obtengas todos los ingredientes y después iteres sobre ellos en donde los estés usando

Comment: Olvidé especificarlo, con modificarlo me referia hasta cambiarle el tipo de método a String, luego dentro lo que especifiqué en el comentario anterior y que al final retorne la variable que recibe el ingrediente.

Comment: Puedes hacer `String ham = pizza.getIngrediente()[0];` perfectamente. Aunque para empezar, yo renombraría todas las variables para que sean en pluran, puesto que devuelven colecciones y no unidades. También puedes modificar el método para que devuelva un `String` y reciba un parámetro `numIngrediente`: `public String getIngrediente(int numIngrediente){ return this.ingrediente[numIngrediente];}` y usarlo directamente: `String chicken = pizza.getIngrediente(2);`

Comment: ¿Qué es el atributo `ingredientes_adicionales`? ¿Son los ingredientes adicionales de una pizza en particular (instancia), o son los ingredientes adicionales disponibles para todas las pizzas (clase)?

Comment: Puede parecer confuso pero el atributo `ingredientes_adicionales`  está definido de esa forma en el enunciado que me asginaron. Como se trata de una pizzeria, según el proceso de pedido, debo ofrecerlos cuando el cliente ya quiera cerrar su pedido.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un poco de confusión.

Para definir directamente los elementos de un array, por ejemplo `String[]`, puedes hacer:

```
new String[]{"Primero", "Segundo", "Tercero"}
```

Esto te crea el `String[]` y lo puedes asignar igual que cualquier otra expresión.

> Destaco que debido a que se trata de arreglos, al utilizar el get de alguno de ellos, solo devuelve la posición de memoria.

No, lo que te devuelve es la referencia al objeto (los arrays son objetos). Es distinto. Lo que la implementación por defecto de `toString()` hace que parezca algo relacionado con la posición de memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Tu constructor inicial, el de la versión original de tu post, no tenía mucho sentido

```
public class Pizza {
    String[] ingrediente;
    String[] tamaño;
    float[] precio;

    public Pizza(String[] ingrediente, String[] tamaño, float[] precio) {
        this.ingrediente = {"Jamón", "Pepperoni", "Pollo", "Vegetariana"};
        this.tamaño = {"Personal", "Familiar"};
        this.precio = {5.50, 12.00};
    }

    public String[] getIngrediente() {
        return ingrediente;
    }

    public String[] getTamaño() {
        return tamaño;
    }

    public float[] getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }
}
```

El constructor esperado con esos argumentos es

```
public Pizza(String[] ingrediente, String[] tamaño, float[] precio) {
      this.ingrediente = ingrediente;
      this.tamaño = tamaño;
      this.precio = precio;
}
```

La solución que has alcanzado gracias a los comentarios y la otra respuesta no es eficiente y no es lo usual. No es necesario que guardes en cada Pizza individual, en cada instancia de Pizza, los ingredientes posibles, ni los tamaños posibles, etc. Lo normal es tenerlos definidos en **constantes a nivel de clase**. Las constantes se definen con los modificadores `static final` y por convención se nombran en MAYÚSCULAS.

```
public class Pizza {
    public static final String[] INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES = 
          {"Jamón", "Pepperoni", "Pollo", "Vegetariana"};
    public static final String[] TAMANIOS_POSIBLES = {"Personal", "Familiar"};
    public static final double[] PRECIOS_POSIBLES = {5.50, 12.00};

    ...
}
```

¿Qué conseguimos con eso? Para acceder a las variables de clase, NO es necesario instanciar una clase, es decir, no necesitamos hacer una pizza para saber cuales son los ingredientes disponibles para la pizza. Y además ahorramos espacio, solo tenemos la lista de ingredientes cargada en memoria UNA SOLA VEZ, en lugar de tantas veces como pizzas haya instanciadas.

Para que te quede claro de que hablo, a continuación una pequeña representación algo más visual. Sea P la representación del almacenamiento en memoria de las variables de clase e INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES la representación en memoria de los ingredientes posibles y Pn las instancias de pizza.

Con tu estructura, si tienes 7 pizzas tendrías en memoria

```
P
P1 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P2 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P3 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P4 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P5 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P6 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P7 [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
```

Con mi recomendación tendrías en memoria

```
P [INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES]
P1 []
P2 []
P3 []
P4 []
P5 []
P6 []
P7 []
```

Podemos acceder a las variables de clase directamente o a través de métodos de clase, declarados como static a su vez.

```
public class Pizza {
    public static final String[] INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES = 
           {"Jamón", "Pepperoni", "Pollo", "Vegetariana"};
    public static final String[] TAMANIOS_POSIBLES = {"Personal", "Familiar"};
    public static final double[] PRECIOS_POSIBLES = {5.50, 12.00};

    public static String printIngredientes() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (String ingrediente : INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES) {
            sb.append(ingrediente);
            sb.append(";");
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Como se puede constatar ejecutando esta clase de ejemplo donde se muestra como puedes acceder a las variables de clase sin tener que hacer un new para obtener una instancia.

```
public class MainPizza {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Pizza.INGREDIENTES_POSIBLES[0]);
        
        System.out.println(Pizza.printIngredientes());

    }

}
```

Salida obtenida

```
Jamón
Jamón;Pepperoni;Pollo;Vegetariana;
```

BONUS: Te recomendaría no usar la Ñ en tu código. Puede darte problemas cuando tengas que subirlo a un repositorio compartido, o lo despliegues en una máquina distinta de tu local que no esté configurada para el español.